# BindingSource Filter - Remove words from string

Tags: c#, checkbox, filter, datagrid, bindingsource

I have a DGrid that is attached to a BindingSource which is full of data. I am trying to use checkboxes for the user to filter out data in a specific column named 'Status'. I have four checkboxes as there will be four different data text in the same column (Column is on the far right).
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20uul.jpg)

Obviously when the user checks/unchecks one of the checkbox it will set a filter to the grid to add/remove that data in the column.

Here is my code which works for when the checkbox is checked:

```
private void chkProgress_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filter = "";

        if (chkProgress.Checked)
        {

            filter = "Status LIKE '%Progress%'";

            if (chkPending.Checked)
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Pending%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }

            if (chkCompleted.Checked)
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Completed%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }

            if (chkArchived.Checked)
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Archived%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {



        }

        MessageBox.Show(filter);
        bs.Filter = string.Format(filter);
        refreshGrid();

    }

    private void chkCompleted_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filter = "";

        if (chkCompleted.Checked)
        {

            filter = "Status LIKE '%Completed%'";

            if (chkPending.Checked)
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Pending%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }

            if (chkProgress.Checked)
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Progress%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }

            if (chkArchived.Checked)
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Archived%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {



        }

        MessageBox.Show(filter);
        bs.Filter = string.Format(filter);
        refreshGrid();
    }

    private void chkArchived_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkArchived.Checked)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void chkPending_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filter = "";

        if (chkPending.Checked )
        {

            filter = "Status LIKE '%Pending%'";

            if( chkProgress.Checked )
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Progress%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }

            if( chkCompleted.Checked )
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Completed%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }

            if( chkArchived.Checked )
            {
                filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Archived%'";
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {


        }

        MessageBox.Show(filter);
        bs.Filter = string.Format(filter);
        refreshGrid();
    }
```

How would I go about REMOVING data from the string filter when they are unchecked? Something similiar to -=?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
if (chkPending.Checked)
{
  filter += " Or Status LIKE '%Pending%'";
}
else
{
  filter = filter.Replace(" Or Status LIKE '%Pending%'", "");
}
```

Comment: Cheers I have used this see my updated question. However sometimes it doesn't seem to Replace the string to nothing. It is intermittent and doesn't about 1 every 6 tries.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint on the replace row and watch the filter-var before and after until it doesn't work as expected.